# Session is not maintained between UIWebView

Tags: swift, uiwebview, nsurlconnection, nshttpcookiestorage

In my app I'm trying to login user through UIWebView. On successful login cookies are set in `NSHTTPCookieStorage`. Few of my app pages are open in UIWebView.

When request for particular web page is send, it check whether user is logged in or not based on the cookies.

I checked that cookies are present in `NSHTTPCookieStorage`, but are not valid cookies on server. That is, it consider user as logged out user.

My code for loading UIWebView is as below:

```
let url = serverURL + urlString
let urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
webPage.loadRequest(urlRequest)
```

Even I tried with `NSURLSession` and setting cookies as HTTPHeaderField. Below is my code for that too:

```
let URLRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)

let cookies = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookiesForURL(NSURL(string: serverURL)!)
for cookie in cookies!{
    URLRequest.setValue(cookie.value, forHTTPHeaderField: cookie.name)
}

let sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

let task = session.downloadTaskWithRequest(URLRequest)
task.resume()
```

It's working properly for few cases. I'm unable to find what can be an issue with the cookies.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider trying `WKWebView` (iOS 8+). With it you can copy `configuration` property from the last used instance to a newly created and _maybe_ this will preserve cookies. Alternatively, use _one_ instance of UIWebView allover the app.

Comment: i am facing similar issue , kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does not do what you intend:

```
for cookie in cookies!{
    URLRequest.setValue(cookie.value, forHTTPHeaderField: cookie.name)
}
```

When cookies are sent over HTTP, they are sent in a `Cookie` header of the format:

```
Cookie: cookie1=value1; cookie2=value2
```

You are creating multiple headers *named* the cookie name, so your request looks like:

```
cookie1: value1
cookie2: value2
```

The easiest way to create the correct headers is with `NSHTTPCookie.requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies(_:[NSHTTPCookie])`.  Since you've added no other headers, you could simply do:

```
if let cookies = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookiesForURL(NSURL(string: serverURL)!) {
    URLRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = NSHTTPCookie.requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies(cookies)
}
```

As an aside, you are using different URLs for your request and for looking up the cookies.  They should be the same as cookies can be scoped to specific paths in a domain.

Comment: Thanks @Brian Nickel. I solved my issue in similar way, but forget to add the answer